# Wired ethernet connection randomly dropping out on 16.04.3 - can't find workable answer

Tags: hardware, connection, nic

Having similar issue with wired ethernet randomly dropping out. Sometimes works fine for hours, other times drops out whenever it feels like. Only way I can resolve is to reboot. Network immediately comes back. 
I have reviewed what seems like half a hundred posts on AskUbuntu and other sites, followed numerous links, and can't seems to find any resolution. 
I'm slowly learning Linux, but certainly not well versed.
My system:
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
ASUS TUF Z270 Mark 2 MotherBoard
Intel I5 – 6600 @ 3500MHz
16GB RAM
Within the BIOS of the MB the only network options for ivp4 or ivp6 is enable or disable.

One link suggested a download from Intel so I went to Intel's website and could not find any downloads for Ubuntu 16.04.3 beyond graphics drivers and the microcode.

As a test I tried using Ubuntu from Live CD rather than hard drive. The version of Firefox from the CD is version 54 and Netflix refused to load (version too old). Network stayed up over an hour and didn't drop out. 
I rebooted and launched Firefox (58) from the hard drive. Worked for 1-2 minutes, then forced to reboot. 2nd time worked fine for several hours.

Not sure why or if it matters, but instead of eth0 my nic is enp0s31f6. Would reloading the network manager be of use? I ran the following command $ sudo  systemctl restart NetworkManager.service and it says the network connection was reestablished, however when opening Firefox it totally hangs and then the connection drops back out in approx 1 minute. Perhaps not the proper command. Having to continually reboot is becoming increasingly frustrating.

Here are some additional commands I ran to give you some idea of my system, and also the error log from the dropout:

*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 10:7b:44:7a:d7:88
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=192.168.0.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:128 memory:df100000-df11ffff

dmesg | grep e1000e
[    0.843061] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.843061] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.901361] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.299126] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.367208] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 10:7b:44:7a:d7:88
[    1.367209] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.367286] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.367704] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
[   29.186313] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx

lspci -v | grep Ethernet
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V

$ ip addr
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:7b:44:7a:d7:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.6/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 3074sec preferred_lft 3074sec
    inet6 2605:e000:7cc9:8700::6/128 scope global deprecated dynamic 
       valid_lft 1669sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 2605:e000:7cc9:8700:2be3:a66d:3f36:443f/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 604779sec preferred_lft 604779sec
    inet6 fe80::6e3b:eb54:8bb:8fa5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Here is the log from dmesg:

Running:
[ 4485.232955] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
After drop:
[ 4487.080266] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: Detected Hardware Unit Hang:
                 TDH                  <0>
                 TDT                  <2>
                 next_to_use          <2>
                 next_to_clean        <0>
               buffer_info[next_to_clean]:
                 time_stamp           <1000ff6e5>
                 next_to_watch        <0>
                 jiffies              <1000ff8b0>
                 next_to_watch.status <0>
               MAC Status             <40080083>
               PHY Status             <796d>
               PHY 1000BASE-T Status  <3c00>
               PHY Extended Status    <3000>
               PCI Status             <10>

Appreciate the assist for a Linux newbie!

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old and hasn't yet been answered. I can add a partial solution. Reboot is not necessary. My ethernet drops out all the time while running on Ubuntu and I have to repeatedly restart the ethernet connection by turning 'wired connnection' off and then turning it on again. So yeah ..  there is that solution to restarting the computer. But I still don't know why it is doing it and it is making the system unusable. I boot windows and it works, so I know there is no problem with the hardware. I offer that a reboot is not necessary and that the partial solution is restarting ethernet, but I wish someone could answer the question better than I have.